# how to send segment number in sabre auto price air exchange soap api request

Tags: c#, soap, sabre

i am trying to implement sabre auto price air exchanges soap api and almost the request is working properly but when i am sending the request with segment number specified the response gives error saying invalid segment selection even if the i am sending the correct segments here is the sample request and response enter image description here

## sabre soap api  error message : "\u0087SEGMENT SELECT INVALID"

Comment: Would you be able to post the full request/response?

Comment: Thanks for help but i have implemented the api including correct segment